# How to find that limit by mathematica?

Tags: summation

[image: lim]

```
Limit[Sum[2(2k)^(1/(2k))-k^(1/k),{k,n+1,2n}]-n, n -> ∞]
```

to solve by hand, 
$$\sqrt[y]y=e^{\frac{\ln y}{y}}\sim1+\frac{\ln y}{y}$$
$$2\sqrt[2k]{2k}-\sqrt[k]k\sim1+\frac{\ln2}{k}$$
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left(2\sqrt[2k]{2k}-\sqrt[k]k\right)\sim n+\ln2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\sim n+\ln 2 \, \int_{n+1}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\left(2\sqrt[2k]{2k}-\sqrt[k]k\right)-n\right)=\ln^22$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I wrote, this is rather math than Mathematica. Let me improve the Bob Hanlon's approach.
First,

```
Series[2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k), {k, Infinity, 1}]
```

> $ O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^2\right)+\frac{\log (2)}{k}+1$

Second, the sum of $O(k^{-2})$ over $k$ from $n+1$ to $2n$ is $O(n^{-1})$ so the one tends to zero as $n$ approaches $\infty$. We need estimates to ground it and this is math.
Now

```
Sum[Normal[Series[2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k), {k, Infinity, 1}]], {k,
n + 1, 2*n}] - n
```

> $ \log (2) \psi ^{(0)}(2 n+1)-\log (2) \psi ^{(0)}(n+1)$

The last step is

```
Limit[%, n -> Infinity]
```

> $\log ^2(2)$

To be sure,

```
N[%]
```

> $ 0.480453$

Comment: Wonderful! Do you know what is the purpose of `AsymptoticSum`? Does it deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: The command AsymptoticSum[
  Normal[Series[2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k), {k, Infinity, 1}]], {k, 
   n + 1, 2*n}, {n, Infinity, 2}] - n performs $\frac{\log (2)}{16 n^2}-\frac{\log (2)}{4 n}+\log ^2(2) $. We need take the limit and this is longer. The command AsymptoticSum[
  2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k), {k, n + 1, 2*n}, {n, Infinity, 2}] - n fails. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I think `AsymptoticSum[
 2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k),
 {k,n+1,2n},
 {n,\[Infinity],1}
]-n` should have produced `-(Log[2]/(4 n)) + Log[2]^2` or more completely `-(Log[2]/(4 n)) + Log[2]^2+O[1/n]^2` (there was fight between SW and others to have the output of `Sum` and `AsymptoticSum` be `SeriesData` in one of the liveCEOs stream). I think it is a bug or since it is experimental they haven't put in all the algorithms. The entire purpose of `AsymptoticSum` is defeated if you have to explicitly give the asymptotic behavior of summand.

Comment: @ user13892: Thank you for your personal opinion. I don't think thatAsymptoticSum[ 2 (2 k)^(1/(2 k)) - k^(1/k), {k,n+1,2n}, {n,\[Infinity],1} ]-n should have produced -(Log[2]/(4 n)) + Log[2]^2 . BTW, what do you mean by SW which is not a standard abbreviation?

Comment: SW = Stephen Wolfram. I distinctly remember that in one of his live stream, he argued with his developers to have `AsymptoticSum` return `SeriesData` rather than the actual expression to have consistency with `Series`. Or maybe I am confusion it with something else.

Comment: Isn't `AsymptoticSum` a behaviour of summed expression around a point approximated to a certain degree like `Series`? So why wouldn't it had produced that result?

Comment: Typo in my second comment: `Series` not `Sum`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a very complicated sum but it does seem to slow done enough to estimate its value and may converge!

Mathematica is not able to solve it analytically in my attempt.

First, a few things to note:

- `n`-th root of `x` in real domain is represented by `Surd` in Mathematica.
- Secondly, you need to take the discrete limit over the integers here.

Now you can try the analytical approach as follows:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[n_]:=Sum[2Surd[2k,2k]-Surd[k,k],{k,n+1,2n}]-n;

DiscreteLimit[
    f[n],
    n->∞
]
```

Maybe someone here can help with how to make Mathematica get to the analytical limit.

But we can estimate its value:

```
list=Table[
    N@f[n],
    {n,1,1000}
];

ListPlot[list,PlotRange->All]
ListPlot[Differences@list,PlotRange->All]
```

Estimation:

```
N@f[10000]
N@f[100000]
N@f[1000000]
```

> 0.479474
>
> 0.480298
>
> 0.48043